# Rxjs global task timer

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs

I am trying to create a global task timer on my app.

I am looking a solution for:
 - when I clicked start progress on task, the timer will count 60 s.
 - but when I change page (another component) and come back to previous one, the timer will be still counting.

Do you think that cold timer obserer it is good idea? I have problem with implement it. Or maybe RxJs has that solution by out of box?

I mean - how is the best idea for timer persist?

Thank you ford the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the timer Observable in a service, making sure to subscribe to it from within the service so that it doesn't lose all subscribers. Something along these lines:

```js
private timer = interval(1000).pipe(take(60));
private timerStarted = false;

startTimer() {
  this.timer.pipe(
    tap(() => this.timerStarted = true),
    finalize(() => this.timerStarted = false)
  ).subscribe();
}

getTimer() {
  return this.timer;
}

getTimerStarted() {
  return this.timerStarted;
}
```

Then, in your component:

```js
private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.timerService.getTimerStarted()) {
    this.timerService.getTimer().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      // handle timer stuff here
    ).subscribe();
  }
}

onStartTimer() {
  this.timerService.startTimer();
  this.timerService.getTimer().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    // handle timer stuff here
  ).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}
```

EDIT: moved the `take(60)` to the Observable itself, and not to the one inside the `startTimer` method. This should prevent it from counting beyond 60 seconds when subscribed to from outside.

Comment: Hmm how can I check the current value of timer?

Comment: You can subscribe to it from wherever you need the current value (as long as it's already started). You can use `take(1)` to get its current value and then complete.

Comment: Working very good! There is a solution to set up maximum value for timer? F.e. 10 seconds?

Comment: That's what I did with the `take(60)` line in the `startTimer` method. It takes 60 emissions and then completes, and because `interval` emits every second, that makes 60 seconds! You could even pass it as an argument to `startTimer`, allowing you to customize your timer each time.

Comment: Oh, after 60 seconds still counting. But I will try to find the solution. Thank You for your big help!

Comment: Aaaah of course, let me edit the answer, I think I have the solution for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! RxJs is not easy :)